# Passing a Texture as a constructor parameter causes error in SFML

Tags: c++, textures, sfml

So I wanted create a texture, and load the texture from a file, then pass that texture (with loaded file) into a constructor to be used for a sprite. However, when I do this, the debug console returns the following **3 times**:

`An internal OpenGL call failed in Texture.cpp(98). Expression: glFlush() Error description: GL_INVALID_OPERATION The specified operation is not allowed in the current state.`

However, it seems that the texture is still loaded when I do this, but even if it loads the texture successfully I don't like that I am getting some sort of error in the debug because it sounds like trouble in the future. To get around this error, I can just pass through a string containing the file location to the constructor, and I will do that if there is no solution, but my code is more organized and readable if I do it the way that gives me an error.

Here is an example code you can copy/paste to test out the error (you will need your own test texture and specify its destination):
**I have commented on the specific lines where the error occurs.**

```cpp
int main()
{
    class Texture_Example
    {
    private:
        sf::Texture testTexture;

        void initializeTexture(sf::Texture testTexture)
        { this->testTexture = testTexture; } // Error called on this line

        void initializeTextureString(std::string textureFile)
        { this->testTexture.loadFromFile(textureFile); }

    public:

        Texture_Example(){}

        Texture_Example(sf::Texture testTexture)
        {
            std::cout << "Constructor with texture" << std::endl;
            this->initializeTexture(testTexture); // Error called on this line
        }

        Texture_Example(std::string textureFile)
        {
            std::cout << "Constructor with string" << std::endl;
            this->initializeTextureString(textureFile);
        }

        virtual ~Texture_Example(){}
    };

    sf::Texture inputTexture;
    inputTexture.loadFromFile("Textures/Test Texture.png");

    Texture_Example usingTexture(inputTexture); // Error called on this line
    Texture_Example usingString("Textures/Test Texture.png");

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried to find the `Texture.cpp` file so I could look at the `glFlush()` code, but I honestly don't know how to find that cpp file. I do not know how to navigate libraries or where to find their code. Besides that, all I tried was making this simple example to see if it still returned the error, and it does, so I am at a loss.

Worst case scenario I pass through a string and try to reorganize my code around that. I have explored the 2 other instances of people asking for help with this error on Stack Overflow, but both of their instances were not nearly as simple as the code I have posted, and did not receive any definite answer.

Comment: https://github.com/Furthen64/hurkalumo/issues/24

Comment: Not any kind of answer to your question, but I would certainly pass texture objects by const reference rather than by value. Your code will be better, and since this seems to be an SFML bug maybe that change will dodge the issue.

Comment: Clearly, the problem is only in the `this->testTexture = testTexture;` since all other problems are caused by calling the function `initializeTexture`. Are you sure the assignment is correct or the lifetime of the textures are long enough?